# Express JS POST Request

Tags: javascript, html, express, routes

I'm trying to do a basic POST Request which stores the email address in a variable and then displays it in the console. The URL for the page is: http://localhost:3000/email-adress (I know it's missing an extra d on address).

For some reason the code isn't working, thoughts?

**Express**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/email-adress', (req, res) => {
  var email = req.body.email
  console.log(email)
})

module.exports = router
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="/finished" method="post">
<label class="" for="email">Email address</label>
<input class="" id="email" name="email" type="text">
<button type="submit" class="">Continue</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: You're trying to post to `/finished`, not `/email-adress`

Comment: you must call `res.send(email)` after console.log

Comment: @AZ_ He's logging server side, he doesn't want to send anything back just yet by the looks of it

Comment: Thanks @jaxi, it kind of works but the end goal is to show that email address value on the finished page. In this first instance I'm just trying to capture the email address value and show it in the console when you press submit. Then the next step is to show it on the finished page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the answer thanks to Jaxi. What I was doing was doing the POST on the /email-adress rather than the /finished so I've amended the Express code to:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/finished', (req, res) => {
  var email = req.body.email
  console.log(email)
  res.render('finished')
})

module.exports = router
```

That solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things here. First, when someone navigates to a url, in your example `localhost:3000/email-adress` (which only works on your machine by the way), the browser is making a `GET` request to the `/email-adress` route. I'm not sure what the rest of your express code is, but you'll have to have a route to handle this to assumably serve your form. Now, with the form served to the front end, if you want to trigger the code in the `POST` route to `/email-adress`, you will have to do that via `fetch`.

I'm assuming you want this to happen once you submit your form. In order to do that, handle the form's submission via JavaScript. Get rid of the `action` and `method` attributes, and do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', onSubmit)

function onSubmit(e) {
  fetch('/email-adress', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: e.target.email.value })
  })
}
```

Now, once you submit the form, you should see a `console.log` happen on your server.